# Why is $f$ a surjective homomorphism?

Tags: group-theory

I'm posting  this question  because  user last seen is more  than $5$ years ago

I have  some  confusion on this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/198879/1004803)

It is written that

> Let $G$ be the set of non-zero elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p$.
> $G$ is a commutative group of order $p-1$.
> Let $f\colon G \rightarrow G^2$ be the map such that $f(m) = m^2$.
> $f$ is a surjective homomorphism.
> Hence $G^2$ is isomorphic to $G/\ker(f)$.
> Since $\ker(f) = \{1, -1\}$ and $p$ is odd, $|ker(f)| = 2$.
> Hence $|G^2| = (p-1)/2$.

**My question** : Why  is $f$  a surjective homomorphism ?

**My thinking** :Let    define the  map  $f : \mathbb{Z}^*_p \to \mathbb{Z}^*_p $ by $f(x)=x^2$

Here order  of $ G=\mathbb{Z}^*_p= p-1$ where $p$ is odd prime

We   can't use  Bezout 's theorem  here  because  $2$ and  $p-1$ are   not relatively prime

This  implies  $f$ is not  surjective

For example   take   $G= \mathbb{Z}^*_3$

$\mathbb{Z}^*_p = \{1,2,3,...,p-1\} \implies \mathbb{Z}^*_3=\{1,2\}$

$f:\mathbb{Z_3}^* \to \mathbb{Z_3}^*$ defined by $f(x) =x^2$

$f(1)=1$  , $f(2)=2^2=4=1 \bmod 3$

Therefore $f$  is not onto

Comment: Note that the range in the quote is $G^2$: the set of all squares of elements of $G$. So, by definition, the map is surjective. Your thinking uses the wrong codomain, it should be $(\mathbb{Z}_p^*)^2 = \{x^2\mid x\in\mathbb{Z}_p^*\}$, which for $p=3$, would be $\{1^2,2^2\} = \{1\}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin      $G^2 = \mathbb{Z}^*_p \times \mathbb{Z}^*_p $.Im not getting  why is   $f : \mathbb{Z}^*_p  \to \mathbb{Z}^*_p \times \mathbb{Z}^*_p $  onto?

Comment: No, here $G^2$ is being used in the sense of group theory, not set theory; for a multiplicative group $G$, and positive integer $n$, $G^n = \langle x^n\mid x\in G\rangle$; if the group  is abelian, this equals $\{x^n\mid x\in G\}$. If the desired interpretation were $\mathbb{Z}^*_p\times\mathbb{Z}^*_p$, then the map would not even make sense, because $x^2$ is not an element of the cartesian product.

Comment: okay @ArturoMagidin

Comment: thanks you  @ArturoMagidin